# OpenNI: Camera calibration file not found

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have calibration file for both RGB and IR camera. However, i'm still getting the `Camera calibration file xxx not found.` even though the xxx is the correct path?

Full console output:

```
Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.

Loading nodelet /xtion2/rgb/rectify_color of type image_proc/rectify to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Loading nodelet /xtion2/rgb/rectify_mono of type image_proc/rectify to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.

Loading nodelet /xtion2/rgb/debayer of type image_proc/debayer to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Loading nodelet /xtion2/ir/rectify_ir of type image_proc/rectify to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Loading nodelet /xtion2/depth/metric of type depth_image_proc/convert_metric to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Loading nodelet /xtion2/depth/rectify_depth of type image_proc/rectify to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Loading nodelet /xtion2/depth/metric_rect of type depth_image_proc/convert_metric to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

/xtion2/depth/image_rect -> /xtion2/depth/image_rect_raw

/xtion2/depth_registered/image_mono -> /xtion2/depth_registered/image_raw

/xtion2/depth/camera_info -> /xtion2/depth/camera_info

/xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect -> /xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect_raw

/xtion2/depth_registered/image_raw -> /xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect_raw

Loading nodelet /xtion2/depth_registered/metric of type depth_image_proc/convert_metric to manager /xtion2_nodelet_manager with the following remappings:

Number devices connected: 2

1. device on bus 001:03 is a PrimeSense Device (600) from PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id ''

2. device on bus 002:03 is a PrimeSense Device (601) from PrimeSense (1d27) with serial id ''

Searching for device with bus@address = 2@0

/xtion2/right -> /xtion2/projector

/xtion2/left/image_rect -> /xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect_raw

Opened 'PrimeSense Device' on bus 2:3 with serial number ''

Could not find any compatible image output mode for 1280 x 1024 @ 15. Falling back to default image output mode 1280 x 1024 @ 30.

rgb_frame_id = '/xtion2_rgb_optical_frame' 

depth_frame_id = '/xtion2_depth_optical_frame' 

Camera calibration file /home/ros/.ros/clopema_calibration/xtion2/camera_rgb.yaml not found.

Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.

Camera calibration file /home/ros/.ros/clopema_calibration/xtion2/camera_ir.yaml not found.

Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressedDepth/set_parameters]

Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]

Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/xtion2/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
```

Output of the ls command:

```
$ ls /home/ros/.ros/clopema_calibration/xtion2/
camera_ir.yaml  camera_rgb.yaml  capture  report
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63122/openni:-camera-calibration-file-not-found./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-05-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-05-21**:
Please copy paste the full console output. Bests regards

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-05-22**:
@Stephane.M I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `Camera calibration file XXX not found.` error message is misleading. The same message is show when the parsing fails. The file was there, but not properly formatted. I have submit an issue [issue](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/issues/14).

---

Originally posted by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) with karma: 801 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mrs Wang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5047/mrs-wang/) on 2013-06-05**:
could you tell me how to solve the problem "Camera calibration file XXX not found"?

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-06-05**:
You should never ask a question as an answer to another question.
However, please not that the "error" Camera calibration file not found is not a problem, as default camera calibrations files exist, and programs work without further calibrations from users.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I post as an answer, as comments are too short. I will edit this during the resolution.)

Ok, from what I see in your copy-past, there is no problem... The calibration files have not been found, but instead it uses the default ones. can you do the following command in a terminal and gives use the output :

"ls /home/ros/.ros/clopema_calibration/xtion2/ "

Bests regards.

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2013-05-23**:
I have posted an update.